# passing credentials to IIS from ws

Tags: sql-server, web-services, iis

In our application we use a WS deployed on IIS 7. To connect to DB we added conn.string to Web Config:

```
<add name="DB" connectionString="Data Source=...;
Integrated Security=False;User ID=sql;Password=xxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I need to use Integrated Sec. to be able to see who did an update in DB. So I have to pass Windows User credentials IIS to be used to connect to DB. What I tried to modify my method in ServiceModel.Client:

```
Client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation
Client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredential
```

I have played with IIS properties- but it gives me the error: `login failed for IIS/AppPOOL/mysite`

Comment: Nobody can help me?

Comment: Looks like nobody

Comment: It'd be easier to grasp the issue if you add some code samples .more details on the issue.